# Ad hoc proof of Minkowski's bound for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-19})$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{-1+\sqrt{-19}}{2}]=\mathcal{O}_K$, where $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-19})$.

A classical way to prove the fact that $R$ is a PID is to establish that for all $a,b\in R,b\neq 0$, there exists $q,r\in R$ such that $a=bq+r$ or $2a=bq+r$, where $\vert r\vert^2<\vert b\vert^2$.

I would like to find a proof of the fact that $R$ is a PID more in the spirit of "class group computations", using Minkowski's bound in disguise. Since I would like to present such a proof to my students (which have no knowledge of the classical results of algebraic number theory),  I would like to avoid the whole machinery of algebraic number theory, so the question is:

**Question.** Given an ideal $I$ of $R$, is there an **ad hoc and down-to-earth** proof of the existence of $z\in K^\times$ such that $zI$ is an ideal of $R$ satisfying $\vert R/zI\vert\leq 2$.

Once we have this, it is easy to see that $zI=R$ or $2R$ (using maximality of $2R$) and we are done.

If it helps, I know an ad hoc proof of the fact that $I=\mathbb{Z}m+\mathbb{Z}z_0$, for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $z_0\in R$. Note that we may assume that $z_0\notin \mathbb{Z}$, and so $m, \mathbb{z}_0$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $I$.

Comment: It is quite easy to prove that there is just one $SL_2 \mathbb Z$  equivalence class of binary quadratic forms of discriminant $-19.$ See Dickson (1929) https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.466075/page/n37/mode/2up   The mapping between forms and ideals is specified in Henri Cohen, section 5., pages 225-230 in A Course in Computational Number Theory.  The recent, very inexpensive book by Lehman follows this pairing all through the book https://bookstore.ams.org/books-on-sale

Comment: table on page 85 of Dickson.  direct link for Lehman book  https://bookstore.ams.org/dol-52/